Redundancia en normalización
Me vendría bien algo de ayuda y de su expertiz.
Estoy normalizando una base de datos para una universidad. Un alumno tiene una licenciatura, la licenciatura pertenece a un plan;  una licenciatura tiene muchas materias y una materia puede estar presente en muchas licenciaturas. Un alumno también puede estar inscrito en muchas materias y una materia puede tener muchos alumnos. Mi duda radica en que si es correcto que en el diagrama relacional se forme una especie de círculo ya que alumno se relaciona a la izquierda con licenciatura que a su vez se va relacionando con materias que son las que pertenecen a la carrera pero alumno a la derecha también se relaciona con las materias que son las que tiene inscritas. Si llego a la tabla materias del lado izquierdo es porque se quiere acceder a las materias de una licenciatura pero si llego del lado derecho se quiere acceder a las materias inscritas por un alumno. Mi maestra de administración de bases de datos dice que no es correcto debido a la redundancia. ¿Cómo resuelvo ese problema? ¿Cómo afecta a la redundancia a la optimización de una base de datos? ¿Alguien tiene una posible solución al problema?
Gracias.


Eso no es redundancia, pero me parece que faltan atributos referentes a la fecha para indicar cuando tomó la materia el alumno, tomando en cuenta que la puede cursar varias veces.

Ese círculo o bucle al que te refieres no tiene por qué ser necesariamente una redundancia y, en este caso, no lo es. Tu maestra, muy acertadamente, quiere que evites las redundancias y los bucles suelen ser un indicador de éstas. Así que la recomendación debería ser: siempre que te encuentres un bucle, analízalo; pero no lo consideres directamente una redundancia.
Para dar con la respuesta tienes que analizar la semántica de los datos que pretendes modelar, y se suele ver con más claridad con datos concretos. En el caso que planteas lo verás fácilmente con las materias optativas de una licenciatura: la licenciatura las tiene que incluir en la tabla Materias_Licenciaturas, pero el alumno no tiene por qué matricularse de todas, por lo que en algún sitio habrá que indicar en cuáles se matricula y en cuáles no. Y ese sitio es Alumno_Materias. Ahora, imagínate el caso de una optativa compartida por varias licenciaturas, ¿cómo podrías saber a qué licenciatura pertenece ese alumno? Pues necesariamente tienes que guardar ese dato, que ya has visto que no es redundante porque no tiene nada que ver con el otro, simplemente porque, sólo con la materia, no puedes saber qué licenciatura cursa un alumno. Por lo tanto, tienen diferente semántica. El significado de ese dato es diferente en uno u otro contexto y, por lo tanto, no se da tal redundancia.
Alguien podría decirte que podrías calcular en qué licenciatura está matriculado un alumno a través de las materias, buscando una materia en la que se haya matriculado ese alumno que únicamente pertenezca a una licenciatura. Pero tampoco sería práctico, porque un alumno se pudo haber matriculado sólo en optativas compartidas por varias licenciaturas y ya no podrías calcularlo.
Lo que veo que no contemplas es que un alumno se matricule en más de una licenciatura, y esa limitación autoimpuesta podría obligarte a tener que rediseñar tu modelo en el futuro, con todo lo que ello implica.
Y ya, lo del plan, se me escapa. Según lo has modelado, una licenciatura únicamente puede pertenecer a un plan. Y eso no sé si es así o no, porque no sé exactamente a qué refieres con plan.
